# Better way to create an object with lot of attributes

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a domain object `Invoice` that has around 60 attributes, some are mandatory and some are optional. This `Invoice` class is a representation of a record in the underlying DB table with certain columns values wrapped with application layer classes (like Enum for a simple integer stored in the DB, Currency for a double etc.,).

This `Invoice` class is currently defined as follows:

- Public full-arg constructor.
- Public getters.
- Protected setters.

Now, it is scaring the clients of this class who create an `Invoice` object, to pass all 60 odd attributes to the constructor. I am adamant against making the setters *public* for obvious reasons.

Could you please suggest a better way to allow creation/modification of this invoice object? Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: There's a good chance that you could break down all these attributes into smaller groups, which could then be wrapped into classes. For example, if you had an xposition and a yposition, you could just use a single `Point` which would contain both. Obviously, you don't have position in your `Invoice` class, but you probably see what I'm getting at.

Comment: I could do that--grouping related attributes into an object. That would still mean that the clients have to build these to create an Invoice object, right?

Comment: Yes, but it would parse it down into more manageable objects, and you could have more "default" values this way. It's easier to create objects one at a time and then stick them into a constructor than pass a single massive line of parameters into the constructor. You could then take advantage of operator overloading in the sub-objects constructors to provide intelligent default values, thereby reducing the work for the clients.

Comment: If you can give a list of at least *some* of the attributes you're passing, then we might be able to help out better.

Comment: Not sure if adding those attributes to question would be breach of any code (I didn't read the fine print properly ;)), but those are typical attributes of an invoice with vendor attributes, currency attributes, quantity related attributes etc.,

Comment: Thanks @JakeKing for your initial idea about breaking them down. I would be going with this approach to make the invoice object creation easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do maybe would be to [decompose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_%28computer_science%29) your object into smaller ones. As per the comments above, you might require the users to build these new objects however, depending on your database design, you might just need to pass a primary or foreign key to the class.

The class will then have some *behaviour* which will seek the relevant data from the database. This obviously could increase the load on your database server, but it will allow you to less complex (albeit, more in amount) classes. The reduction in complexity will most likely increase the chances of code re-usability as well as make it more maintenance friendly.

Comment: +1, I will end up with more manageable chunks after decomposition. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

### *Using* the Builder Pattern

Use the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)  that Joshua Bloch describes in his  book [*Effective Java 2nd Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683). You can find the same example in http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue163.html

Pay special attention to the line:

```
NutritionFacts locoCola = new NutritionFacts.Builder(240, 8) // Mandatory
                          .sodium(30) // Optional
                          .carbohydrate(28) // Optional
                          .build();
```

### *Using* `BeansUtils.populate`

Other way is to use the method [`org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(Object, Map)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29) from [Apache Commons BeansUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/). In this case, you need a map to store the object's properties.

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("servingSize", 10);
    map.put("servings", 2);
    map.put("calories", 1000);
    map.put("fat", 1);

    // Create the object
    NutritionFacts bean = new NutritionFacts();

    // Populate with the map properties
    BeanUtils.populate(bean, map);

    System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(bean,
            ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));

}
```

**Output**:

```
NutritionFacts@188d2ae[
  servingSize=10
  servings=2
  calories=1000
  fat=1
  sodium=<null>
  carbohydrate=<null>
]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still require, in some cases, the need to pass all 60 attributes?

Comment: @npinti only if you need all 60 attributes

Comment: +1, I knew about the Builder pattern but the suggestion from @npinti helped me how to couple the both--decomposition and builder to make this a more manageable and readable piece. Thanks.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Yes I know that, hence the *some cases*.

Answer (score 0):

As suggeste @Jake King , it is always better to 60 attributes to composite into smaller data objects.

While doing this, I will look into one aspect, which possible combinations are optional and I will compose in that way. For example, Mailing Address is optional if Client Clicks on to say that use the Current Address and Mailing Address.

Build Constructors around these composed objects will help you manage/maintain the Class easily and effeciently.

Answer (score -3):

If your Invoice Object has 60 attributes and you are sure that you wont be requiring some of them there is no need create getter and setter for those attribute.it is always recommended to create getter setter of the attributes which you required in code. but you need to make sure that the omitted field should allow null contraint in database.

else if you required all the 60 attributes in the code then create different contructor as per required by the client.if client needs to pass only 4 then create contructor accepting 4 parameters and you can set default values for attributes in the database whose values are not passed by the clients.